# remove class if other nav is clicked bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 mobile navbars in my bootstrap site. I know its not the best idea but with the design this company did I have no choice. I need help getting the glyphicons to flip back to the down position when it closes. I have some script to close one if the other nav toggle is clicked but the glyphicon doesn't flip back. I know this is something on the easier side but I am pretty new to bootstrap and writing scripts. Here is my code:

```
        <div class="header"><div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-4 logo hidden-xs"><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive" title="Logo" src="images/Logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 login-wrapper hidden-xs">
                    <ul class="list-inline header-list">
                        <li>Login to sphere</li> 
                          <li id="myMode-glyphicon" class="pull-right list-unstyled dropdown modeSelector">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Shippers <span class="modeSelect glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a><ul class="list-unstyled dropdown-menu" role="menu"><li><a href="#">sphere</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Trucks</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      <form class="login-form" role="login">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="user-input form-control" placeholder="Username">
                          <input type="text" class="pass-input form-control" placeholder="Password">
                          <button type="submit" title="Login" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </form></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 search-wrapper hidden-xs">
                      <form class="search-form" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search">
                          <button type="submit" title="Search TMC" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button></div></form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand hidden-md hidden-xl hidden-sm hidden-lg" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" title="Logo" src="images/Logo.png" alt=""></a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="autocollapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"><span class="menu-toggle-text">MENU <i class="myMenu-glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
                        <span class="menu-toggle-text">LOGIN <i class="myLogin-glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
    </button>
    </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <form class="search-form mobileSearch-form hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-xl hidden-lg" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit" title="Search TMC" class="btn btn-default mobileSearch-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICES</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu hover-dropdown hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <div style="height:5px; background-color:#fff;"></div>
                <ul class="list-inline hidden-xs">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>       
          </li>
            <li><a href="#">PLACEHOLDER</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-md hidden-xl hidden-sm hidden-lg mobileLogin">
                <li>
                  <ul class="header-list list-unstyled">
                    <li class="list-unstyled mobile">Login to sphere</li> 
                      <li id="myMode-glyphicon-mobile" class="list-unstyled dropdown modeSelector">
                        <a  href="#" class="mobileDropdown dropdown-toggle mobile" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Shippers <span class="modeSelect glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></a>
                        <ul class="mobileList list-unstyled dropdown-menu mobile" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">sphere</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Trucks</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <form class="login-form" role="login">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="user-input form-control longin-control" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="text" class="pass-input form-control login-control" placeholder="Password">
                    <button type="submit" title="Login" class="btn btn-default mobileSearch-btn pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->


    </nav>  
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
           $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
           $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
        });

        $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
           $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
        });

       $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
           $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
        });

        $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
           $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
        });
                if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('shown.bs.collapse') ){
                    (".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
            };
</script>
```

I tried to do this but it did not work. I wonder if I should create a bootply?

```
<script>
// FLIP ALL THE GLYPHICONS NAVBAR

   $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open");
    });


   $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open");
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
    });

    if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
    (".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael I think you know your a life saver here. I was able to figure this out with your code here. I am not sure how much I can clean this up and make sure it doesn't take a long time to load though. I am pretty new to Bootstrap and JavaScript but I think this does the trick. The only issue I had with your code as it sits was that it would hide the glyphicon when the other button was clicked, and even when that particular button was clicked the glyphicon would just hide. Here is how I did this, again please let me know if there is an easier way to write this bit of logic because I am sure there is. Thanks a huge great deal Michael for your help on this!)

```
    <script>
    // FLIP ALL THE GLYPHICONS NAVBAR

   $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open").removeClass("dropdown-closed");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-2').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
          $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
          $("#navbar-collapse-2").removeClass("dropdown-open");
          $("#navbar-collapse-2").addClass("dropdown-closed");
       };
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).removeClass("dropdown-open").addClass("dropdown-closed");
    });


   $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open").removeClass("dropdown-closed");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
          $("#navbar-collapse-1").removeClass("dropdown-open");
          $("#navbar-collapse-1").addClass("dropdown-closed");
       };
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up")
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).removeClass("dropdown-open").addClass("dropdown-closed");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       };
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error lies in this part:

```
if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('shown.bs.collapse') ){
    (".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
};
```

`shown.bs.collapse` is not a class that is applied to the element but rather an event.

You are on the right track through.  You can modify the listeners on the first nav to change the class of the first navbar to signify that there is an open nav as such, then in second navbar code check if the first navbar has the dropdown-open class.

```
<script>
// FLIP ALL THE GLYPHICONS NAVBAR

   $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open");
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).removeClass("dropdown-open");
    });


   $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-2').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       };
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up")
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).removeClass("dropdown-open");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       };
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to add code the correct way in a comment.

Comment: use back ticks ` around the code (same as the tilda key ~)

Comment: Did I add your code correctly? I think I did but limited explanation is making this a little confusing as to how to add it.

Comment: Try moving that last bit of code `if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){     (".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");` into the callback function for navbar-collapse-2 on shown.be.collapse

Comment: `$('#navbar-collapse-2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
      $(this).addClass("dropdown-open");
    if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
        (".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
    };
    });`

Comment: I added it like this but still did not work. I moved this line of code around into a few spots and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to clean up the code and put it all in context, give it a try.